# Kotlin cast digit arrayList elements intoBigDecimal

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, casting, bigdecimal

I have arrayList `val k = listOf<Any>("a","b","2","c","3")` I would like to get in new list a list of Strings and BigDecimal if it is a Digit (2,3). How to perform that?

```
val c:List<Any> =
```

Comment: In general `List<Any>` is a bad idea. Work with concrete types that represent your data. Why is your input list `List<Any>` instead of `List<String>`? Why do you want `BigDecimal` when `2` and `3` fit into a single byte? Why do you want to mix strings and numbers?

Comment: Also: **casting does not mean converting a value into a new type: casting means promising the compiler that it's _already_ the required type.**  I think this question is talking about conversion, not casting.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, but I think it's a bad idea. If you give us more context to your problem, I'm sure there will be a much better approach. Note that this converts all valid numbers to `BigDecimal`, not just `2` and `3`.

```
val c: List<Any> = k.map {
    it.toString().let { str ->
        try {
            BigDecimal(str)
        } catch (e: NumberFormatException) {
            str
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner (note that this converts all valid numbers to `BigDecimal`, not just `2` and `3`):

```kotlin
val c: List<Any> = listOf<Any>("a","b","2","c","3").map { it.toString().toBigIntegerOrNull() ?: it }
```

If you omit the `Any` type parameter of the original list, Kotlin will infer it as `String`, so this could be simplified:

```kotlin
val c: List<Any> = listOf("a","b","2","c","3").map { it.toBigIntegerOrNull() ?: it }
```